# How to perform unit testing on highcharts in angular9?

Tags: angular, highcharts, karma-jasmine

I am having a component defined in angular9 which uses a highcharts API.
Now i want to perform a unit testing on the highcharts.
For eg:
If the data fetched is correct or not.
The highchart is created or not.
Any idea of how it can be done using Jasmin and  karma.
THanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is mostly related to writing tests in Angular than using the Highcharts library (which tag you had used). From Highcharts site I can only suggest to base on Highcharts tests: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/unit-tests

Answer (score 0):

i think the best solution for u case to use jest and mock ur highcharts

```
const highcharts = jest.genMockFromModule(`highcharts`)
```